# Trying to create a field in gravity Forms that hides the information as it types, similar to when inputting a password

Tags: php, function, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating an application and need the potential hirees to put in their SSN. I am having some trouble creating a Line Text Field that as the hiree types will hide the numbers, similar to when you're putting in your password.

Anyone know how to do this? I've already edited the functions.php in an attempt to add 'encrypt' to the advanced settings but that only encrypts the data once its submitted, not immediately turning it into dots as the enter it.

Comment: Why not use a password field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Single Line Text fields, you can select the [Enable Password Input](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/663382/560af8734a08762ebb9bcc52a41adf2c) option to mask the text like a password input.